# How to projection paint an artistic (and not straight draw) of a face on a 3d model

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting, dynamic-paint

Let's say that I want to project paint the image below :

[image: anastasia]

on a **3d model**,what methods you suggest to me ? I'm trying to use the classic **project painting** tecnique,but the problem is that the picture is **not taken in front of someone**,but it is a draw that I created my self,so it has an **odd inclination** and it's difficult to paint on the **3d model** if the picture is not straight. I want to project paint the image on the head of a 3d humanoid model,preserving the expressiveness and then I want to **animate the face with the expressions**...it's been a long time that I'm trying to do this,trying different tecniques,but I never been satisfied...I have a lot of draws that I want to **convert in 3d models**,like you can see below...

[image: ada]
[image: silvia]
[image: daniela]

Below you can see some pictures that explain very well how much confusing is working with a transparent image :

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]

Comment: maybe you should first create your mesh, then paint the texture on it

Comment: I already tried,but I'm not able to match the texture with the facial features,such as the eyes,the mouth,etc...I need to inclinate the 3d model to do this but anyway they does not match and the whole procedure is tricky...

Comment: you need to take a basic modeling course first, what you ask is not difficult to do for someone who has 2 years of blender experience, it is very difficult to guide you, because you can not correct your modeling errors at the moment, I I suggest you study a basic course and then make a plan to develop your project

Comment: your paintings are not a texture and can not be assembled in a 3D model that does not have that shape, by telling you to paint the textures in the model, it is literally painting on the faces of the model, not that you put your painting on the model

Comment: Hand Paint is it https://i.imgur.com/q60P8M1.png

Comment: I don't like to paint directly to the 3d model. I will not reach the same face expressiveness. I would like to know if there is another tecnique.

Comment: there's no solution to your problem, if it doesn't match when you paint a mesh I don't see how any of your draw could match on any mesh, maybe you should explore the new Grease Pencil (2.8 version), it's very powerful, intuitive, and it really fits your style, and you could mix your characters with some 3D objects

Comment: can you suggest a tutorial that I can follow ?